# Asynchronous recursive JavaScript function returns same value and terminates abruptly

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, recursion

Every time I run the following function, I expect it to output the different paths embedded in my composer.json file and then perform this recursively for each package. However, it just gives me the same result over and over again. Please what am I missing here?

```
const packageComposer = async (node) => {
    node = node ? __dirname : node;
    let composer = fs.readFileSync(node + '/composer.json', 'utf8');
    let dependencies = Object.keys(JSON.parse(composer).require);
    console.log(node + '/composer.json');
    dependencies.forEach(key => {
        let dependency = key.split('/');
        let dir = node + '/vendor/' + dependency[0] + '/' + dependency[1];
        if (fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            packageComposer(dir);
        }
    });
}
```

Composer.json file looks like:

```
{
  "require": {
    "php": ">=7.2",
    "alek13/slack": "^2.1",
    "composer/installers": "^1.7",
    "htmlburger/carbon-fields": "^3.3"
  }
}
```

Console output:

```
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/composer.json
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/composer.json
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/composer.json
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/composer.json
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/composer.json
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/composer.json
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/composer.json
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/composer.json
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/composer.json
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/composer.json
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/composer.json
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/composer.json

RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
Exception in PromiseRejectCallback:
/Users/user/Desktop/github/plugin-folder/gulpfile.js:59
}
```

Comment: Can you add some more context? What does `composer.json` look like? Did you save the file?

Comment: Why is this function `async`?

Comment: To restate @Andy, it's not doing anything async in the body (even the recursive call isn't awaited).  I think there's two levels of problems here: (1) about what *should be* async and how to handle async recursion, (2) about what's going wrong with parsing of the file and the assumptions about what the parse will find.  I suggest attacking these in reverse order.  To address the latter, pls post some lines from the file and some console output.

Comment: @jfriend00 I asked because I don't know. Your comment has neither helped nor explained what I could do better. I have provided useful context on how I am trying to use this by showing the output of my console.log, the least you could do was point me in the right direction.

Comment: We get a lot of questions here where people are just throwing random `async` and `await` keywords in them without any reason.  It is clear many other people have not done any learning about when to use these or how to use these.  I asked here because perhaps you actually have an asynchronous operation you plan to use here and aren't showing it to us - because if that is so, then it would change the answer completely.  Otherwise this is 100% synchronous code and should not be `async`.  If you had a reason for making it `async`, I'd like to know what that reason is.

Comment: Andy asked why it's `async` and you haven't yet answered him.  This is relevant to an answer.  I removed my previous comment on the topic because it was a bit snarky.  My apologies.

Comment: Can you describe in words what you're trying to recursively iterate here?  What does the directory and file structure look like that you're trying to iterate?  Can you show us that?

Comment: In trying to understand your code, why are you doing `key.split("/")` and then reassembling the same two pieces with `dependency[0] + '/' + dependency[1]`?  Why not just use the key as you found it?  And, what are you expecting to happen when there is no `/` to split on like the `php` key you show in your sample?

Answer (score 2):

I was wondering why your console output never shows a path with `/vendor` in it because your recursive logic intends to create a path that has `/vendor` in it.  Then, I realized, that's because this logic:

```
node = node ? __dirname : node;
```

is backwards and will always select `__dirname` when you pass a value for `node`.  So, every recursive call ends up using the same value for `node` and thus an infinite loop that eventually overflows the stack.

Instead, you want this:

```
node = node ? node : __dirname;
```

The MDN description for the ternary operator is this:

```
condition ? exprIfTrue : exprIfFalse
```

Another way to do this is to use default parameters and let the JS engine supply a value when nothing is passed and write is this way:

```
const packageComposer = async (node = __dirname) => {
   ...
};
```

For any further debugging, I might suggest this cleaned up version with logging that lets you follow where it goes:

```
function packageComposer(node = __dirname) {
    // read and parse composer.json using require()
    const filename = path.join(node, 'composer.json');
    console.log(`About to read ${filename}`);
    let composer = require(filename);
    const dependencies = Object.keys(composer.require);
    console.log("Found dependencies", dependencies);
    for (const key of dependencies) {
        const pieces = key.split("/");
        const dir = path.join(node, 'vendor', dependency[0], dependency[1]);
        if (fs.existsSync(dir)) {
            console.log(`Calling packageComposer(${dir}) recursively`);
            packageComposer(dir);
        }
    }
}
```

As I said in my comments, a couple things seem odd here.  You do `key.split("/")` to get the pieces of a key such as `"alek13/slack"`, then you immediately put them back together again to reconstruct `"alek13/slack"` again.  Not sure why you're doing that or what you expect to happen when the keys can't be split and you've got a key like `"php"` that doesn't contain a `"/"`.